# What does PrintJob.defaultPage() returns?

Tags: java, printing

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#:%7E:text=defaultPage,-public%20PageFormat%20defaultPage&text=PageFormat%20defaultPage()-,Creates%20a%20new%20PageFormat%20instance%20and%20sets%20it%20to%20a,a%20default%20size%20and%20orientation.) says it creates a new pageFormat instance and sets it to default size and orientation. What is default here? Is it printer specific page ?

Comment: How about calling the various getters of `PageFormat` to see for youself?

Comment: Likely it uses a session or OS specific configuration, like the printer properties of the default printer in Windows. For example, on my machine it is A4 and portrait, but for someone in the US it's probably Letter and portrait. But I could change my printer config to use Landscape as the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark said, the default page format is obtained from the PrintService of the PrinterJob.

The internal sun.print.RasterPrinterJob class has this:

```
public PageFormat defaultPage(PageFormat page) {
    PageFormat newPage = (PageFormat) page.clone();

    Paper newPaper = new Paper();

    double ptsPerInch = 72.0;
    double w, h;

    Media media = null;

    PrintService service = getPrintService();
    if (service != null) {
        MediaSize size;

        media = (Media)service.getDefaultAttributeValue(Media.class);
        if (media instanceof MediaSizeName &&
           ((size = MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName((MediaSizeName) media)) != null)) {

            w =  size.getX(MediaSize.INCH) * ptsPerInch;
            h =  size.getY(MediaSize.INCH) * ptsPerInch;
            newPaper.setSize(w, h);
            newPaper.setImageableArea(ptsPerInch, ptsPerInch,
                                      w - 2.0*ptsPerInch,
                                      h - 2.0*ptsPerInch);
            newPage.setPaper(newPaper);
            return newPage;
        }
    }
```

And if the print service isn’t defined, the method falls back to guessing:

```
/* Default to A4 paper outside North America. */
String defaultCountry = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
if (!Locale.getDefault().equals(Locale.ENGLISH) && // ie "C"
    defaultCountry != null &&
    !defaultCountry.equals(Locale.US.getCountry()) &&
    !defaultCountry.equals(Locale.CANADA.getCountry())) {

    double mmPerInch = 25.4;
    w = Math.rint((210.0*ptsPerInch)/mmPerInch);
    h = Math.rint((297.0*ptsPerInch)/mmPerInch);
    newPaper.setSize(w, h);
    newPaper.setImageableArea(ptsPerInch, ptsPerInch,
                              w - 2.0*ptsPerInch,
                              h - 2.0*ptsPerInch);
}
```

(I’ve taken the liberty of formatting and trimming the above code in some places, for clarity.)

So, in summary, the method returns:

- The PrintService’s default page size if available (that is, the printer’s default page size, which probably comes from the printer’s default tray)
- Otherwise, if the runtime locale is not English, use a portrait A4 page
- Otherwise, fall back to the default Paper, which is [8½×11 inches with a 1-inch margin](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/print/Paper.html#%3Cinit%3E()).